# FireStore Update Document doesn´t work

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working with Firestore, trying to update a document. I have a button that toggle the favorite property of the object then send the updated object to Firestore.

```
toggleFavorite: function(e, user, photo){
  e.preventDefault();
  if(!user.isAnonymous){
    photo.toggleClass('start-on');
    var current_photo = {},
    photos = [],
    alt = photo.siblings('.img-responsive').attr('data-name'),
    photo_id = photo.attr('data-id');
    app.loop_user_photos(photos);
    $.each(photos, function( i, v ){
      if(alt == v.name){
        current_photo = {photoId : v.id, photoObj: v};
        return;
      }
    });
    var pic_ref = db.collection("Traumhochzeit_pictures/"+app.current_user.uid+"/pictures/").doc(photo_id);

    var favorite = (current_photo.photoObj.favorite) ? false : true,
    updates =  {
      "favorite" : favorite
    };

    return pic_ref.update(updates);

  }
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to get the current picture from an array of pictures, create a reference to the document in Firestore, change the property of the object then update. My problem is that only one work, when clicked the first time, changed the property `favorite` and updated the document in Firestore but when clicked again, doesn't update. Any idea?